# Table of Contents in Latex Book

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I'm writing a thesis using

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,book,twosides]{now-book}
```

When I generate the table of contents, it results something like this:

> Chapter 1 (chapter name)
>
> 1 (section name)
>
> 2 (section name)
>
> 2.1 (subsection name)

I'd like to include the chapter number in each line as in the following.

> Chapter 1 (chapter name)
>
> 1.1 (section name)
>
> 1.2 (section name)
>
> 1.2.1 (subsection name)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  do the sections in the body of the thesis include the section number, or, if they don't, can they?  it's much easier if they're numbered the same in both the body and the toc.

Comment: Hi! They don't, but actually I'd like them to appear as well in the body, e.g., 1.2 (section name) where in this case 1 is the chapter number and 2 is the section number.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of it, but `now-book` is not a standard class, and not available on CTAN, so most people here can't try this themselves. Is that a local class at your university?

More common classes like `book` and `memoir` do it as you want to have it.

Comment: Is one of the document class options spelled `twosides`, or should it be `twoside`?

Comment: @Mico It is spelled
    twosides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind printing the chapter number with the other sectional units *wherever they appear* (not just in the ToC, but in the text as well), just add

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
```

to your preamble. This *should* cascade down to the subsection level as well, since the subsection should use `\thesection` as part of its numbering construction, just like I've done for the section numbering above.